# How to subtract aggregate min from aggreagate max(difference) in ES?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to write an ES query to find the difference between max and min value of a field?

I am a newbee in elastic search,
In my case I feed lot of events along with session_id and time in to elastic search.
My event structure is

```
Event_name string    `json:"Event_name"`
Client_id  string    `json:"Client_id"`
App_id     string    `json:"App_id"`
Session_id string    `json:"Session_id"`
User_id    string    `json:"User_id"`
Ip_address string    `json:"Ip_address"`
Latitude   int64     `json:"Latitude"`
Longitude  int64     `json:"Longitude"`
Event_time time.Time `json:"Time"`
```

I want to find the life time of a session_id based the feeded events.
For that I can retrive the maximum Event_time and minimum Event_time for a particular session_id by the following ES query.

```
{  
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
     "match": {
        "Session_id": "dummySessionId"
     }
  },
   "aggs": {
      "max_time": {
         "max": {
           "field": "Time"
          }
       },
       "min_time":{
          "min": {
            "field": "Time"
          }
       }
    }
  }
```

But what I exact want is (max_time - min_time)
How to write the ES query for the same????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to elasticsearch 1.1.1, **this is not possible** to do any arithmetic operation upon two aggregate function's reasult from elasticsearch side.
If you want then, you should do that from client side.

That is neither possible through scripts, as @eliasah suggests.

In the upcoming versions they may be add such facility.

Comment: I got the same answer from the google groups too. [Link Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/6uXG2HjzP9o)

Answer (score 2):

in the 1.5.1 using the [Scripted Metric Aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) you can do this. Not sure about the performance, but it looks to work. **This functionality is experimental and may be changed or removed completely in a future release.**

```html
POST test_time

POST test_time/data/1
{"Session_id":1234,"Event_time":"2014-01-01T12:00:00"}

POST test_time/data/3
{"Session_id":1234,"Event_time":"2014-01-01T14:00:00"}

GET /test_time/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Session_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "session_lenght_sec": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            "map_script": "_agg['v'] = doc['Event_time'].value",
            "reduce_script": "min = null; max = null; for (a in _aggs) {if (min == null || a.v < min) { min = a.v}; if (max == null || a.v > max) { max = a.v }}; return (max-min)/1000"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

###### RESPONSE #######
{
   ...,
   "aggregations": {
      "by_user": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 1234,
               "doc_count": 2,
               "session_lenght_sec": {
                  "value": "7200"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is bound to the Elasticsearch 7.8 version.**
Followed up the @pippobaudos answer ahead. Elasticsearch has made some major changes since the answer.

the aggregation has a type '[scripted_metric](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html)' (click on the link to know more), which has new sub-attributes such as init_script, map_script, combine_script, reduce_script. Out of which, only init_script is optional. Following is the modified query.

```
"aggs": {
    "cumulative":{
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": {
          "source": "state.stars = []"
        },
        "map_script": {
          "source": "if (doc.containsKey('star_count')) { state.stars.add(doc['star_count'].value); }"
        },
        "combine_script": {
          "source": "long min=9223372036854775807L,max=-9223372036854775808L; for (a in state.stars) {if ( a < min) { min = a;} if ( a > max) { max = a; }} return (max-min)"
        },
        "reduce_script": {
          "source": "long max = -9223372036854775808L; for (a in states) {  if (a != null && a > max){ max=a; } } return max "
        }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving directly the query will not help you much, so I suggest you read the documentation about [Script Fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) and [Scripting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html).

Comment: I tried the same, but Aggreagation can't be used in Scripts

Comment: Did you try something like [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html#_script)?

Comment: Nop, But how can I use max aggregation inside min aggregation script, I think both of them are metric aggregation.

Comment: Did you try to run a script of the `min` and `max` you obtain outside of `aggs`?

Comment: Could you please add an example query or link of using min or max inside script. I googled but still don't know how to write.